# Есть ли такое выражение "поднять труды"?

Tags: фразеология, значение-слов

Он первый поднял труды для установления мира в стране.

Comment: Это выражение встречается в религиозных текстах. *Поэтому поднять труды, которые поднимали подвижники тех времён, для нас будет большим подвигом, нежели для них* (http://vladimir-olga.cerkov.ru/2017/04/)

Answer (score 1):

Если судить по цитате из [этой книги](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=cF1EAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%20%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8B%22&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB%20%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8B%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO2O2zxt7XAhXByqQKHRTvBBUQ6AEILzAC), можно предположить, что в былые времена такое выражение в подобном значении могло использоваться. Насколько я знаю, оно не сохранилось до наших времён и не будет понято носителями языка.

Выражение "поднять труды" в наше время чаще всего имеет значение "просмотреть литературу (как правило, научные работы), написанную кем-то или по какой-то тематике" и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "поднять труды" существует и означает "осилить труды", а вот употреблять его в вашем примере совсем некорректно.